# How to calculate average percentage in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, average, percentage, kpi

[image]

Hi everyone,

I'm still new to PowerBI, right now I have a set of data in PowerBI as shown in the screenshot above. I have a `Measure` to calculate the % of `OK`:

```
total_student = COUNT(StudentAns[Name])

ok_% = 
VAR OK_COUNT = COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        StudentAns,
        StudentAns[Answer] = "OK"
    )
)

RETURN (OK_COUNT/StudentAns[total_student])
```

I created a Matrix to show the % of `OK` for each month as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

What I want to find is the average percentage for all the months. So the final output answer should be 89.05%, which is the average of 85.95%, 91.4%, 89.27% and 89.58%.

The reason I want to get the average percentage of `OK` across all the months is because I want to use the output as a Target Goals for KPI visualization.

Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 89,05 is the average if you take the percentages per month, but 89,50 is the percentage if you take all values. Is there a specific reason why you would want the average over the percentages per month? Say for example you have 100 values, 99 are OK and 1 is incorrect, the first 4 months have all ok, the 5th month has 1 value: incorrect. You would get 80% in your calculation, but the real ok percentage would be 99%. I hope you understand my explanation.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can calculate and get the 89.50% and use it as the Target goal for KPI card?

Comment: Possibly you could copy paste your existing measure and add the ALL function to the calculation steps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax This way you'll do the calculation over all rows, ignoring any filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more measure to the matrix as follows:

```
ok_2 % =
IF(
    HASONEVALUE( 'StudentAns'[Month] ),
    [ok_%],
    AVERAGEX(
        VALUES( StudentAns[Month] ),
            [ok_%]
    )
)
```

It calculates your original measure for each month, but for the Totals it returns the average of results of your measure.

HASONEVALUE returns True if there is only one distinct value in the filtered context; VALUES - creates a list of unique values;  AVERAGEX - calculates the average of a set of expressions evaluated in each row.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I managed to get the Average % for all the months in Totals, however, when I put the measure into the Target Goal for KPI card, it actually used the latest month % as the target instead of using the average %, do you have any idea how should I solve this?

Comment: Hi @weizer The KPI visual is supposed to show the last period (last month), but we can apply ALL function to clear that filter. A measure for the target goals: ok_3 % =
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(
        VALUES( StudentAns[Month] ),
            [ok_%]
    ),
    ALL( 'StudentAns'[Month] )
)

Comment: THanks Andrew!! Really appreciated ur help, I'm looking for this for almost one week! Thank you very much :D